# oAuthRequest returns empty array

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have created a Twitter application for a website. I would like to integrate the possibility of logging in/registering with Twitter. I am using php files as helpers, which are named TwitterOAuth.php and OAuth.php, respectively. When a user clicks on the Twitter button, he/she is redirected to a page called twitter.php, which has the following source-code:

```
<?php

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = Common::twitter();

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(App::env()->get('url'));

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['twitter'] = array('id' => $request_token['oauth_token'], 'token' => $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    var_dump($request_token);
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

The `Common::twitter()` function is as follows:

```
/**
 * Returns the twitter OAuth service.
 * 
 * @return TwitterOAuth
 */
public static function twitter() {
    if (!self::$tw) {
        if ((User::isLoggedIn()) && (User::current()->hasTwitterAccount())) {
            self::$tw = new TwitterOAuth(
                App::env()->get('twitter', 'consumerKey'), 
                App::env()->get('twitter', 'consumerSecret'),
                App::CurrentUser()->getTwitterId(),
                App::CurrentUser()->getTwitterUserAccessToken()
            );
        } else {
            self::$tw = new TwitterOAuth(
                App::env()->get('twitter', 'consumerKey'), 
                App::env()->get('twitter', 'consumerSecret')
            );
        }
    }        

    return self::$tw;
}
```

In the scenario I am testing with, the else branch is executed. However, I get an exception:

> Exception 'PHPErrorException' with message 'Notice [8] Undefined
>   index: oauth_token Error on line 81 in file ...\lib\TwitterOAuth.php

The function where the problem occurs is as follows:

```
  /**
   * Get a request_token from Twitter
   *
   * @returns a key/value array containing oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
   */
  function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback; 
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }
```

The problem is that `OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request)` returns an empty array. This is happening, because `$request` is `false`, however, `$this->requestTokenURL` is https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, `$parameters` has an `oauth_callback`, which holds the callback URL defined in the Twitter application. What could be the cause of this issue?

EDIT:

```
Source of `$this->oAuthRequest`:

  /**
   * Format and sign an OAuth / API request
   */
  function oAuthRequest($url, $method, $parameters) {
    if (strrpos($url, 'https://') !== 0 && strrpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) {
      $url = "{$this->host}{$url}.{$this->format}";
    }
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->token, $method, $url, $parameters);
    $request->sign_request($this->sha1_method, $this->consumer, $this->token);
    switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
      return $this->http($request->to_url(), 'GET');
    default:
      return $this->http($request->get_normalized_http_url(), $method, $request->to_postdata());
    }
  }
```

This method is inside of TwitterOAuth.php.

Comment: You forgot to add source of `$this->oAuthRequest`

Comment: @AlexBlex, thank you for the observation, I have added the method to the question.

Comment: @AlexBlex, this is not a Drupal project and the problem is independent of Drupal.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Must be a naming collision. The signature of the method looks identical to http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules!contrib!oauth!lib!OAuth.php/function/OAuthRequest%3A%3Afrom_consumer_and_token/cis7

Comment: @AlexBlex, no problem, it is because that Drupal module might be using the very same TwitterOAuth I am using. So, TwitterOAuth is more widely used than the Drupal module, hence, it is not Drupal specific, but certainly, this problem might occur at that Drupal module as well.

Comment: Fair enough, could you hare a link to the library?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: Which version?  There is nothing like `OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token` in the current master there. The closest match I found is `Request:: fromConsumerAndToken` https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/Request.php#L41

Comment: Ok, found myself. It was in `0.2.*`. The current version is  `0.6.2`.

Comment: @AlexBlex, yes, sorry, I was eating and did not see your question.

Comment: No worries. Apparently curl returns `false` in the `http` method. I would check it there and throw an exception with `curl_error($ci)` here https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/0.2.1/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L210  It should shed some light why it happens.

Comment: I am looking exactly there. If you find the answer earlier, then I will surely accept it.

Comment: @AlexBlex, the exact error is 'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:80 ', error number 35

Comment: Why 80? It must be 433. It seems similar to http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1319/  I believe it should be reproducible from command line `curl -v https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the port. Can you write an answer so I can thank you for your effort by accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OAuth.php there was a code chunk in the `get_normalized_http_url` method, namely:

```
$port = @$parts['port'];
```

This caused some errors, so I have fixed it like this:

```
$port = (array_key_exists('port', $parts) ? $parts['port'] : 80);
```

However, apparently port number 80 was the problem and after I changed the chunk to this:

```
$port = (array_key_exists('port', $parts) ? $parts['port'] : 443);
```

it worked like a spell.